# Overstayed tourist visa in Spain

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, overstaying, indonesian-citizens

I would like to ask few details because I have been overstayed my tourist visa in Spain, almost 3 months now, and I would like to go back to my country (Indonesia), 
What would be the consequences I face in airport immigration? 
Please help, 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Penalties that may apply include a fine on departure,  and/or a ban for one or more years. Certainly you will find it difficult to get another Schengen visa any time soon.

Exact penalties and implementation vary by country. Spain has tended to be more relaxed about fining departing overstayers, while Germany and the Nordic countries have been more strict. Policies change, however.

The only way to find out what will happen is to leave. Be prepared to be questioned and possibly detained for a while.

Comment: @TomasBy I believe it is the country from which the traveler is departing. If that is correct, it's a bit odd, since it means that someone who has spent (for example) six months in Spain, having flown there by way of Frankfurt, will be penalized by Germany rather than Spain.  Whether the visa was issued by Spain, Germany, or for that matter Finland, or whether the person spent any time in any given Schengen country, is not relevant unless German law takes it into account in determining the penalty.

Comment: @phoog: it would be even more odd if it was the other way around (and perhaps more work for the border guards).

Comment: @TomasBy that's true.  A better solution would be to have uniform penalties specified by the Schengen codes, but I suppose that was not politically possible.